# Can i remove docString from karate html report?

Tags: dsl, karate

The html report generated in karate is displaying all the headers which is a security breach for my organisation .

Is there any way we can remove the doc strings from the report and only show print statement and passed status.

Comment: Thanks for helping with abort() function. can you please help me this one as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this section of the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

So you can "switch off" logs and steps at any time:

```
* configure report = false
```

But please note that logs continue to be available in the `target/surefire-reports` folder, so if this is a security problem, you need to delete those files as well after a test run.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `logback-test.xml` (Log configuration) file in your project  and change the logger level from `DEBUG` to `INFO`

```
<logger name="com.intuit" level="INFO" />
```

This eliminates logging request or response details in log.

Please refer [Karate Logging](https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging)

Comment: I have removed this complete line from the logback-test.xml file . This is only hiding the logs in console ( in my case eclipse console ) but the actual html report contains the complete doc string .